# Select dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a div dynamically and attached to div. I'm trying to add data from query and load it to that text field. But, I'm unable to select the dynamically created elements because its not visible in the DOM,  since its already loaded. 
This is what I have [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhuy3hfs/)

```
<div id="parent">
    <input id='childButton' type="button" value="Add"/>
    <div id="child" data-row="0">
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </div>

</div>


var rowNum = 0;
$('#parent').on('click', '#childButton', function() {  
    var clone = $('#child').clone().attr('data-row', ++rowNum);
   $('#parent').append(clone);
   console.log($('#child[data-row=1]').length);
});
```

Comment: Same `id` on cloned element is the issue

Comment: Explain **unable to select the dynamically created elements**. How you are selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the id selector, will return only the first element with the given id. In your case you are creating multiple elements with the id child. So `#child` will return the first `child` element, but then applying the `data-row` rule will filter out the selected element so you are getting `0` are the result.

The solution is to use a class instead of id to select the element

```js
var rowNum = 0;
$('#parent').on('click', '#childButton', function() {
  var clone = $('#child').clone().attr('data-row', ++rowNum).removeAttr('id');
  $('#parent').append(clone);

  //here clone refers to the dynamically create element
  //but if you want to fetch the element using a selector then

  snippet.log($('.child[data-row=1]').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <input id='childButton' type="button" value="Add" />
  <div id="child" class="child" data-row="0">
    <input type="text" value="" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're cloned element with same id, if you want to check just use

```
console.log($('div[data-row=1]').length);
```

Like others said, an `ids` should be unique. Use class definition instead for child id name.

Answer (score 1):

When you're cloning an element with id, change the id ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhuy3hfs/1/)):

```
var rowNum = 0;
$('#parent').on('click', '#childButton', function() {  
    var origin = $('#child');
    var originId = $('#child').attr('id');
    var cloneId = originId + rowNum;
    var clone = $('#child').clone().attr('data-row', ++rowNum).attr('id', cloneId);
   $('#parent').append(clone);
   console.log($('#' + cloneId).length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dr05amej/)

```
var rowNum = 0;
$('#parent').on('click', '#childButton', function() {  
    var clone = $('#child').clone().attr('data-row', ++rowNum);
   $('#parent').append(clone);
   console.log($('#parent input:text').length);
});
```

You can also select the input by using the selector `input:text`

`UPDATE`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dr05amej/1/)

IF you want to select the specific input to set value into you can use the index and set the value by finding that index

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector is wrong it must be:

```
console.log($('#child[data-row="1"]').length);
```

and consider to remove the id attr in order to avoid multiple ids.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o1j7z1gL/